# Interlace (merge) two spilled ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to merge two spilled ranges of equal sizes so that the first column of spill range A sits next to the first column of spill range B.

I'm close to an answer, but at the same time I've got this feeling I'm going about it completely the wrong way.

**As an example:**
In `A1` enter the formula `=SEQUENCE(3,2,1)`.
In `A5` enter the formula `=CHAR(SEQUENCE(3,2,65))`

This will give the two ranges below.  The result I'm after is in rows 9:11.
[image]

My thoughts have been to do it with `FILTERXML`.

This joins the two ranges and starts building the xml string (entered in cell `F1`):

```
=LET(ColumnNum,COLUMN(A1#),
     FirstTable, A1#,
     SecondTable, A5#,
     PrefixA, "<a" & ColumnNum & ">",
     SuffixA, "</a" & ColumnNum & ">",
     PrefixB, "<b" & ColumnNum & ">",
     SuffixB, "</b" & ColumnNum & ">",
     xml, PrefixA & FirstTable & SuffixA &
          PrefixB & SecondTable & SuffixB,
     xml)
```

This finishes off the xml and returns the final spilled range.

```
=LET(StartCol,COLUMN(F1),
     xml,F1#,
     LastCol,StartCol+COLUMNS(xml)-1,
     finalxml,"<y>" & TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,IF(COLUMN(xml)=StartCol,"<x>","") & xml & IF(COLUMN(xml)=LastCol,"</x>","")) & "</y>",
     CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(xml)*2,1),
            FILTERXML(finalxml,"//x/a1"),
            FILTERXML(finalxml,"//x/b1"),
            FILTERXML(finalxml,"//x/a2"),
            FILTERXML(finalxml,"//x/b2")))
```

This works fine for two ranges of two columns, but the number of columns will change so the `CHOOSE` statement would need to be manually updated each time.

Is there a way to get this working?  Happy to take `LAMBDA` solutions, but afraid I can't use the new `TEXTSPLIT` type functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula easier to scale up compared to your current one:

`=LET(t_count, 3, tables, (A1#,A5#,A9#), row_count, ROWS(INDEX(tables,0,0,1)), col_count, COLUMNS(INDEX(tables, 0, 0, 1)) * t_count, s, SEQUENCE(row_count, col_count, 0), INDEX(tables, INT(s / col_count) + 1, INT(MOD(s, col_count) / t_count) + 1, MOD(s, t_count) + 1))`

Or the same formula broken down for better overview:

```
=LET(
    t_count, 3, 
    tables, ( A1#, A5#, A9#), 
    row_count, ROWS(INDEX(tables, 0, 0, 1)), 
    col_count, COLUMNS(INDEX(tables, 0, 0, 1)) * t_count,  
    s, SEQUENCE(row_count, col_count, 0), 
    INDEX(
        tables, 
        INT(s / col_count) + 1, 
        INT(MOD(s, col_count) / t_count) + 1, 
        MOD(s, t_count) + 1
    )
 )
```

To modify the formula, you just need to update `t_count` and list all your ranges for `tables`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick.  Think I was getting close after I'd stopped looking at FILTERXML and used INDEX instead.  Saved me another day of head scratching. :)

Answer (score 1):

In A9 put

```
=INDEX($A$1#,0,INT((COLUMN()-1)/2)+1)
```

and in B9 put

```
=INDEX($A$5#,0,INT((COLUMN()-1)/2)+1)
```

Now copy A9:B9 to C9:D9.

If you have more than two columns to interleave, just keep on copying onwards from E9 in ranges of multiples of two columns.

Also if you have three of more "source" ranges, just extend the  formula for the third or fourth range, and change the "/2" to "/3" or "/4" or how many more ranges your are working with.

EDIT: I couldn't think of a way to parse this from a single dynamic range formula at first. Excel unfortunately doesn't allow joining arrays using static array syntax e.g. {A1#, A5#} is not allowed. However, the recent addition of MAKEARRAY and LAMBDA present an interesting solution:

**Single formula solution!**

```
=LET(ranges, ($A$1#,$A$5#), rangecount, AREAS(ranges), rangetext, CELL("address",ranges), MAKEARRAY(ROWS(INDEX(ranges,0,0,1)),COLUMNS(INDEX(ranges,0,0,1))*rangecount, LAMBDA(r,cc, INDEX(($A$1#,$A$5#),r,INT((cc-1)/rangecount)+1,MOD(cc-1,rangecount)+1))))
```

Unfortunately you cannot use *ranges* inside the lambda function for some reason (a bug, I think). So easiest is just to define your ranges twice - ones in the LET statement and once as part of INDEX.

Comment: Thanks, your single formula solution looks like it works. I wanted to avoid multiple formula/copy pasting as it isn't going to be me that keeps the spreadsheet updated.  I've gone with the other solution provided as it doesn't include LAMBDA - my employer isn't the fastest at updating and I think I'm the only one in the building who has it at the moment.